# Android icon dimensions

Tags: android, icons

I am using a .png image for the icon of my Android app. The problem is the image dimensions (aspect ratio) is not preserved when displaying the icon. For example the circle image is distorted to an oval shape when set as the app icon.

Comment: Are the icon files square? (i.e. 48x48 pixels)

Comment: refer to this article http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Try this link it may help you to re-size icon and add https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/

Comment: @AlexanderZhak: The page you linked to may contain the answer, but it's a very long page and I have not yet found the answer through a few minutes of browsing. There are no hits for "aspect ratio" on the page. If you know the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to the launcher icon, right?
According to [Making Beautiful Android App Icons](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/07/making-beautiful-android-app-icons.html), the launcher icon should be square. I had a launcher icon that was not square, and it got stretched (distorted) into a square in the launcher on some devices. The solution I found was to add more (transparent) area on the sides to make it square.